# Scrapy crawl a local website by IP address

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm still experimenting with Scrapy, and I'm trying to crawl a website on my local network. The website has the IP address 192.168.0.185. This is my spider:

```
 from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
 class 192.168.0.185_Spider(BaseSpider):
      name = "192.168.0.185"
      allowed_domains = ["192.168.0.185"]
      start_urls = ["http://192.168.0.185/"]

      def parse(self, response):
          print "Test:", response.headers
```

And then in the same directory as my spider I'd execute this shell command to run the spider:

```
scrapy crawl 192.168.0.185
```

And I get a very ugly, unreadable error message:

```
 2012-02-10 20:55:18-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.14.0 started (bot: tutorial)
 2012-02-10 20:55:18-0600 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats,   
 TelnetConsole,     CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, MemoryUsage, SpiderState
 2012-02-10 20:55:18-0600 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares:      
 HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware,  
 DefaultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, 
 HttpCompressionMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
 2012-02-10 20:55:18-0600 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares:   
 HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware,  
 DepthMiddleware 2012-02-10 20:55:18-0600 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
 Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 5, in <module>
 pkg_resources.run_script('Scrapy==0.14.0', 'scrapy')
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 467, in run_script
 self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1200, in run_script
 execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Scrapy-0.14.0-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts   
 /scrapy", line 4, in <module>
 execute()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Scrapy-0.14.0-py2.6.egg/scrapy/cmdline.py",  
 line 132, in execute
 _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Scrapy-0.14.0-py2.6.egg/scrapy/cmdline.py",   
 line 97, in _run_print_help func(*a, **kw)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Scrapy-0.14.0-py2.6.egg/scrapy/cmdline.py",  
 line 139, in _run_command cmd.run(args, opts)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Scrapy-0.14.0-py2.6.egg/scrapy/commands   
 /crawl.py", line 43, in run
 spider = self.crawler.spiders.create(spname, **opts.spargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Scrapy-0.14.0-py2.6.egg/scrapy  
 /spidermanager.py", line 43, in create
 raise KeyError("Spider not found: %s" % spider_name)
 KeyError: 'Spider not found: 192.168.0.185'
```

So then I made another spider, which is practically the same as the first one, except it uses a domain name rather than an IP address. This one worked just fine. Does anyone know what the deal is? How can I get Scrapy to crawl a website via IP address as opposed to a domain name?

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
class facebook_Spider(BaseSpider):
     name = "facebook"
     allowed_domains = ["facebook.com"]
     start_urls = ["http://www.facebook.com/"]


     def parse(self, response):
         print "Test:", response.headers
```

Comment: Well, I have to ask -- why would you *ever* use an ip address to describe a host?  They're not naturally descriptive like hostnames, so I recommend using them sparingly.

Comment: I'd suggest you to learn Python before using complex frameworks like scrapy, django etc. You can chose tutorial from [Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers)

Answer (score 9):

```
class 192.168.0.185_Spider(BaseSpider):
    ...
```

You can't use class name which begins with digit or contains dots in Python. See documentation [Identifiers and keywords](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)

You can create this spider with correct name:

```
$ scrapy startproject testproj
$ cd testproj
$ scrapy genspider testspider 192.168.0.185
  Created spider 'testspider' using template 'crawl' in module:
    testproj.spiders.testspider
```

Spider definition will look like this:

```
class TestspiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'testspider'
    allowed_domains = ['192.168.0.185']
    start_urls = ['http://www.192.168.0.185/']
    ...
```

And probably you should delete `www` from `start_urls`. To start crawling, use spider name instead host:

```
$ scrapy crawl testspider
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to add some check in scrapy to prevent creating invalid class names.